# I can't figure out how to access SvelteKit stores in an exported function

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

I am exporting this function to use in multiple components of my SvelteKit app.

```js
import { session } from '$stores/global';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

export const getSession = () => {
    if ($session) {
        return $session;
    } else {
        const sessionId = uuid();
        session.set(sessionId);
        return sessionId;
    }
};
```

Here is the store setup:

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { browser } from '$app/environment';
export const session = writable(browser ? localStorage.getItem('session') || '' : false);
```

I get `referenceError: $session is not defined at getSession` errors.  Whenever I move the function to the component directly, the function works perfectly.  I've done some reasearch and looked around and tryed using .get() and some other things but all have had different errors.  What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get` is not an instance function, it's an import from `svelte/store`. So:

```js
const $session = get(session);
```